# Symfony2: @Template annotation and PHP templates

Tags: php, symfony, twig

When I use Symfony, I name my views with the name of the corresponding action, so that I can use a `@Template` annotation without any parameters to render the view.

```php
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/show", name="entity_show")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id) {
}
```

Does this only work with Twig? Is there a way to not having to specify the name of the view as a parameter for `@Template` when I use PHP views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Patt wrote, you must specifiy the engine for each use of the annotation:

```
@Template(engine="php")
```

Comment: Thank you elnur. This works indeed, and it's a little bit less verbose than having to write the name of the view, although I would like to be able to omit this too